# oAuth - how to acquire an access token from another org via an Apex callout

Tags: apex, webservices, oauth2

I want to actually connect to a salesforce environment in the background and retrieve information there. I don't want to be redirected anywhere with a  token in the url. I want to be able to get the token in my webservice like this :

```
public with sharing class AP_SandboxRefreshInitSetup {
   public String domain;
   public string endpoint;
   String username;
   String password;
   String clientId = 'my client id';
   String clientSecret = 'my secret'; 

   public AP_SandboxRefreshInitSetup(String domain,string username, string pwd){
      this.domain = (domain != null ? domain : 'https:test.salesforce.com'); 
      this.username = username;
      this.password = pwd;       
   }    
   public void getToken1(){
      String Access_Token;
      Http httpCls = new Http();
      HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
      request.setEndpoint(domain + '/services/oauth2/authorize');
      request.setMethod('POST');

      request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');        
      request.setBody('response_type=code' + 
                    '&client_id=' + clientId + 
                    '&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1/' + 
                    '&username=' + username +
                    '&password=' + password);        

      //sending the json to the request body
      httpResponse response = httpCls.send(request); 
      system.debug('## response:' + response);

       if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){            
         system.debug('## response message :' + response.getBody()); 
         JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());

         while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
             (parser.getText() == 'access_token')) 
            {
                parser.nextToken();
                Access_Token = parser.getText();    
            }
            system.debug('## Access_Token :' + Access_Token);
          } 
       }
       else{
          system.debug('## response status :' + response.getStatus()); 
          system.debug('## response message :' + response.getBody()); 
       }
    }
}
```

I Keep getting status found, with status code 302.

My redirectUri, clientid and client secret is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work using the password response type as follow :

```
 public with sharing class AP_SandboxRefreshInitSetup {         
     String username;
     String password;
     String accesstoken ;
     String instanceURL ;
     String clientId;
     String clientSecret;    

     public AP_SandboxRefreshInitSetup(string username, 
                                  string pwd,
                                  string clientId,
                                  string clientSecret)
     {        
         this.username = username;
         this.password = pwd;    
         this.clientId = clientId; 
         this.clientSecret = clientSecret;  

     }
     public void startTransfert(){
        //step 1 : get the access token
        Http httpCls = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000);  

        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');        
        request.setBody('grant_type=password' + 
                    '&client_id=' + clientId + 
                    '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + 
                    '&username=' + username + 
                    '&password=' + password);        

          //sending the json to the request body
          httpResponse response = httpCls.send(request); 
           //system.debug('## response:' + response);

          if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){            
               system.debug('## Successfully retrieving access token' ); 

               map<string,Object> resultMap = (map<string,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

               accesstoken = (String)resultMap.get('access_token');
               instanceURL = (String)resultMap.get('instance_url');            

               //step 2 : use the token for the salesforce api call


           }
           else{
             system.debug('## Could not retrieve the access token' ); 
             system.debug('## response status :' + response.getStatus()); 
             system.debug('## response message :' + response.getBody());             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`response_type=code` is an authorization grant type (flow) in oAuth, it involves a redirect with an authorization code which you then exchange for an access token (see [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm)). You're expecting an access token to come back right away, this is not the flow that does this.

For service-to-service calls, [JWT Bearer flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) is the recommended option. If both sender and recipient service is Salesforce, you could also try an out of the box [Salesforce auth provider](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_sfdc.htm&type=5) (it uses OpenID Connect underneath the hood).